# react js react-router with arrows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

Friends, please help me. I want to change menu pages with arrows (">" "<")...I must to find active page, and then go back, or forward...

export const ArrowNav = () => {
const menu = useContext(menuContext)

```
const path = () => {
    for (let item of menu){
        if(item.active){
            
        }
    }
}

return <div className="lmpixels-arrows-nav">
    <NavLink to={path}>
        <div className="lmpixels-arrow-right">
            <i className="lnr lnr-chevron-right"/>
        </div>
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink to={path}>
        <div className="lmpixels-arrow-left">
            <i className="lnr lnr-chevron-left"/>
        </div>
    </NavLink>
</div>
```

}

Comment: this will not work, because your `path` is a function, not string. There are few ways to achieve it and one of them is to Add buttons instead navlink and add custom onClick function (onClickPrev or onClickNext) which will trigger `history.push(PATH_HERE)`.

Comment: Do you want to have a full page scroll left/right with arrows?

Comment: please add `menuContext` implemention

Comment: const history = useHistory()

    const onClickNext = () => {
        history.push()
    }

    const onClickPrev = () => {

    }

and what I must push in History???